# Dual Booting tips (ASUS 1015e-DS02)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, asus

I have an ASUS 1015e-ds02 which has ubuntu 10.4 preinstalled. I would like to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 7 (or 8 whichever can support my wireless card). I snooped around for some help on this site and I went on Gparted to check out the partitions.

[image]

This is a screenshot of my current HD untouched, however I am not 100% sure which partition is safe to delete. Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Well it's hard to tell which partitions are safe to delete by just looking at that screenshot. First, what do you want to do exactly? As far as I can see on the screenshot, you already have an NTFS partition, which appears to be from a Windows installation so you already appear to have a dual-boot.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! Well, I would like to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 7. I noticed there is an NTFS partition with 105 GBs of free space, I'm just not sure whether installing W7 on the NTFS partition would tamper with the performance of Ubuntu. Any advice would be useful, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Installing windows on the `/dev/sda5` ntfs partition would not tamper with the performance of Ubuntu.It doesn't cause any damages to your preinstalled Ubuntu Os.

After installing windows on `dev/sda5`,don't forget to run *boot-repair*.